# Have to click twice OnPress React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with my onPress function, I have to click twice on each TouchableOpacity for the style to change.
on Web development its works just fine, I use expo ios iPhone to see the App but it doesn't work like on the web.
I have no idea why but I have to click twice and then it's changing.
any help?

```js
const Test = ({ navigation }) => {
  const itemsData = GetGroceryIngridients();

  const [items, setItems] = useState(itemsData);

  const handleSelectItem = (selectedItemIndex) => {
    const itemsToSelect = items.map((item, index) => {
      if (selectedItemIndex === index) item.pressed = !item.pressed;
      return item;
    }, []);

    setItems(itemsToSelect);

    // your logic here
    AddToPanetry(items[selectedItemIndex].label);
  };

  const renderItem = (item, index) => {
    const isSelected = items[index].pressed;

    return (
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, isSelected && styles.selectedButton]}
        onPress={() => handleSelectItem(index)}
      >
        {
          <Image
            style={{ height: 110, width: 100, borderRadius: 50 }}
            source={item.image}
          />
        }
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate("IngridientsScreen")}
        >
          <Ionicons
            style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
            name="arrow-back-circle-sharp"
            size={50}
            color="#eb344f"
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {itemsData.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    opacity: 1,
    padding: 20,
  },
  selectedButton: {
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
});

export default Test;
```

My GroceryIngridients Array =

```js
const GroceryIngridients = [
  {
    label: "pasta",
    image: require("../assets/Pastaa.jpg"),
    pressed: true,
  },
  {
    label: "eggs",
    image: require("../assets/eggs.jpg"),
    pressed: true,
  },
  {
    label: "white_flour",
    image: require("../assets/whiteflour.jpg"),
    pressed: false,
  },
  {
    label: "rice",
    image: require("../assets/rice.jpg"),
    pressed: false,
  },
  {
    label: "breadcrumbs",
    image: require("../assets/breadcrumbs.jpg"),
    pressed: false,
  },
];
```

any other way to display it welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems it is a small mistake (should loop the state)

change this

```
{itemsData.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}
```

to this

```
{items.map((item, index) => renderItem(item, index))}
```